# How can I switch my Wacom tablet to operate left handed on Windows 10?

Tags: wacom

I finally upgraded computers and had to go with Windows this time around because it was a really good deal.  I don't prefer one OS over the other as long as it gets the job done.  I'm having a problem however with my tablet now on my new set up.  It's running Windows 10 and I don't have a mapping menu to switch the orientation of my tablet around so I can work left handed.  I've tried installing the previous drivers and the most recent drivers from Wacom but that hasn't helped.  Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: I'm not on Windows.. but my Wacom prefs have no "left handed" option. that disappeared a few years ago. You just set which side you want the Express Keys on.. that's all. Then turn the tablet how you want it. (Note I don't use a mouse or the touch features.. not sure if they change for lefties).

Answer (score 1):

In your settings go to the pen settings > Mapping. I'm taking this screen shot off my mac but it works the same in windows. Change the dropdown from '**Express Keys Left'** to **'Express Keys Right'**
[image]